# F# naming convention

Tags: .net, f#, naming-conventions

Is there an "official" naming / casing convention for F#?

I'm always in doubt of using C# style or not:

```
Class.MyFunctionName or Module.my_function_name
```

In F# you're meant to mix BCL classes and F# library ones: they have different casing and the code looks very ugly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there is confusion, because F# has morphed from OCaml to .Net over the years. Basically, the naming conventions are a "breaking change" - old code is inconsistent with new code.

However, the May 2009 CTP has settled the issue.

The [Release Notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2009/05/20/detailed-release-notes-for-the-f-may-2009-ctp-update-and-visual-studio-2010-beta1-releases.aspx) say...

**Standard Library Naming Conventions**

> The naming conventions adopted for the F# library are as follows:
>
> - All .NET and F# OO code uses PascalCase according to existing .NET guidelines
> - The F# functional programming operators such as List.map are for use in F# internal implementation code. This kind of code uses camelCase for operator names
> - Underscores should not be used.

**So, your question...**

```
Class.MyFunctionName or Module.my_function_name
```

The answer is

> Class.MyFunctionName and Module.MyFunctionName (**but see edit below!**)

(applying rule 1 above).

-- Edit. Nov 2, 2019 --

The [current guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/formatting#use-camelcase-for-module-bound-public-functions) recommend camelCase for functions at module level, so it's

> Module.myFunctionName

Which then makes production code consistent with the F# libraries (eg. List.averageBy)

Comment: Update - in the latest release, the to_type functions have been dropped in favour of toType

Comment: Thanks. To keep it simple, I removed the text which mentions them.

Comment: This is not in line (anymore) with the current guidelines. Module-bound public functions should use camelCase. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/formatting#use-camelcase-for-module-bound-public-functions

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke. Thanks for the info - I've updated the answer. I'm glad to see it - I've always used this convention anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer might have changed since the time of the currently accepted answer.

The [F# Style Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/) today says:

> **Use PascalCase for type declarations, members, and labels**
>
> Classes, interfaces, structs, enumerations, delegates, records, and
>   discriminated unions should all be named with PascalCase. Members
>   within types and labels for records and discriminated unions should
>   also use PascalCase.
>
> ```
> type IMyInterface =
>     abstract Something: int
>
> type MyClass() =
>     member this.MyMethod(x, y) = x + y
>
> type MyRecord = { IntVal: int; StringVal: string }
>
> type SchoolPerson =
>     | Professor
>     | Student
>     | Advisor
>     | Administrator
> ```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/formatting#use-pascalcase-for-type-declarations-members-and-labels

and

> **Use camelCase for module-bound public functions**
>
> When a module-bound function is part of a public API, it should use
>   camelCase: F#
>
> ```
> module MyAPI =
>     let publicFunctionOne param1 param2 param2 = ...
>
>     let publicFunctionTwo param1 param2 param3 = ...
> ```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/formatting#use-camelcase-for-module-bound-public-functions

So, based on those, my answer is that this:

```
Class.MyFunctionName 
Module.my_function_name
```

Should be written like this:

```
Class.MyFunctionName  
Module.myFunctionName
```

Answer (score 3):

Anything official: I think "not quite yet", but whenever VS 2010 reaches Beta1 you'll probably see the F# library in its nearly-final form, and there will be a number of renamings relative to the CTP.  F# will probably always be a little more schizophrenic than its older .NET cousins, given its history.

Comment: Hi Brian, what do you mean by "F# will probably always be a little more schizophrenic than its older .NET cousins, given its history"? Thanks.

Comment: History: F# is derived from OCaml, and F# still retains a core that is very largely source-compatible with OCaml.  But OCaml has different naming convention than .Net.  So F# is pulled in two different directions.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding and current usage is that module/static functions have lower case, and 'instance' functions have upper case.

**Edit** not an answer to this question, but related: [F# Formatting conventions](http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/expert-fsharp-draft/FormattingConventions.doc) by Don Syme

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen from hubfs.com and other sources, its a mix from .net and OCaml.

I hope they switch to either one and not have two different conventions and being Microsoft i am sure they will go with the dot net style.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is any real solution. It seems that perhaps OCaml-ish code might retain some of its naming, i.e., lowercase module methods, whereas OO members will go .NET style.